# Setting up my bashrc environment on terminal

Tags: bash, path, terminal

How can I get **/Users/username/depot_tools** to be apart of the list when I enter the command `echo $PATH`. Currently this is what terminal gives me:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ bianca$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

But what I want is:

```
/Users/bianca/depot_tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH="/Users/username/depot_tools:$PATH"
```

You can also add this to your `~/.bashrc` file to have it set whenever you start a terminal.

Also see [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path).